# Pyarmor Pack Python File Check Restrict Mode Failed

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, py2exe, pyarmor

So i am trying to Pack my python script with pyarmor pack however, when i pack the script it does not work, it throws check restrict mode failed. If i Obfuscate the script normally with pyarmor obfuscate instead of pack the script it works fine, and is obfuscated fine. This version runs no problem. Wondering how i can get pack to work as i want my python file in an exe

I have tried to compile the obfuscated script with pyinstaller however this does not work either

Wondering what else i can try?

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, fixed by adding `--restrict=0`

For example: `pyarmor obfuscate --restrict=0 app.py`

Comment: How can i do this when using prarmor pack command as i want to compile to exe

Comment: Sorted it with pyarmor pack -x " --restrict=0" -e " --onefile" app.py

Comment: also read the Documentation, it helps alot
https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/